# Migrar requisição JSON de android para swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estou com um problema ao migrar um código de um app android para um código em swift.

Esse código é responsável por autenticar o usuário e senha de uma aplicação.

Não estou conseguindo fazer rodar em swift 2 no xcode 7 para iOS 9.

Segue o código em java abaixo:

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
            postParameters = new ArrayList<>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", mUser));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(sUrl);

            HttpResponse httpResponse;

            try {
                String base64 = Base64.encodeToString((mUser + ":" + mPassword).getBytes(),
                        Base64.NO_WRAP);
                httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
                httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error on request login", e);
                return false;
            }

            int responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            return responseCode == 200;
        }
```

Comment: O que você já tentou até agora? Se você já tem algum código, mesmo que não esteja funcionando, poste assim fica mais fácil de lhe ajudar.

Comment: Fiz uma nova postagem com o código que estou tentando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente algo assim:

```
let userPasswordString = "\(mUser):\(mPassword)"
let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"]

let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
let url = NSURL(string: sUrl)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 30.0)

let post = "login=\(mUser)&password=\(mPassword)"

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {(data, response, error) in
    if let httpResponse: NSURLResponse = response {
        if let statusCode: Int = (httpResponse as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode {
            if statusCode == 200 {
                let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print(dataString)
            }
        }
    }
}

task.resume()
```

A sua resposta está na variável `dataString`, como parece que você só espera um retorno **HTTP 200** ou diferente, é só prosseguir com a sua lógica a partir do `statusCode`.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz recentemente uma autenticação de login com o POST em swift. Utilizei o código abaixo:

```
  let URL = NSURL(string:  "http://linkdoseuservidor")

  let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)

  mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

  let parameters = ["email":"asd@hotmail.com", "senha":"2345"]

  do {

        mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())

        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(mutableURLRequest, completionHandler: {

            (data, response, error) in

            guard let responseData = data else {

                print("Error: did not receive data")

                return
            }

            guard error == nil else {

                print("error calling POST on /posts/1")

                print(error)

                return
            }  

            let post: NSDictionary

            do {

                post = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: []) as! NSDictionary
            }

            catch {

                print("error parsing response from POST on /posts")

                return
            }

            print("resultado: ")

            print(post)

            let dataJSON = post["data"] as! NSDictionary

            print(dataJSON)

            print(post["status"])

            let dataString:NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            print(data.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\'", withString: "\""))

            do{

                let dataJSON:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataString, options: []) as! NSDictionary

                let idUsuario = dataJSON["id"]

                let nomeUsuario = dataJSON["nome"]

                print(idUsuario)

                print(nomeUsuario)

            }

            catch let e as NSError{

                print (e)

                print("error data string json")

            }

        })

        task.resume()

    }

    catch {

        print("error parsing response from POST on /posts")

        return
    }
```

Mas é aconselhável fazer a divisão de responsabilidades, usar classes como service e controllers para dividir a responsabilidade da chamada, mas esse código funcionou comigo, espero que lhe ajude.

Comment: As linhas:

let dataString:NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
print(data.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\'", withString: "\""))

Estão com o seguinte erro: Value of type 'NSData?' has no member 'dataUsingEncoding'

Answer (score 0):

Estou chamando a função da seguinte forma:

func validaLogin(){
        let mUser:NSString = txtUsuario.text!
        let mPassword:NSString = txtSenha.text!

```
    let userPasswordString = "\(mUser):\(mPassword)"
    let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"]

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
    let url = NSURL(string: "http:minhaURL")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 30.0)

    let post = "login=\(mUser)&password=\(mPassword)"
    NSLog("post %@", post);

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {(data, response, error) in
        if let httpResponse: NSURLResponse = response {
            if let statusCode: Int = (httpResponse as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode {
                if statusCode == 200 {
                    let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    NSLog("dataString %@", dataString!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume();
}
```

Como faço pra validar os erros?